# Transform XML into HTML table with XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML file and need to transform it into an HTML table with XSLT. I tried to follow an example from w3cschools. It's too burdensome to type it in here because it's not in English, but I'll try to explain my problem:

I have a root element "catalog" and multiple child elements "cd". When I edit the table in XSLT, I only get the values for the first child node "cd".

Can anyone tell where the mistake is?

Comment: You really do need to show your XSLT, because otherwise it will be almost impossible for anyone to tell you where your mistake is. And you should also show a sample of your XML. It does not have to the complete XML, but maybe one with just one or two `cd` elements in. It doesn't matter if the names of the CDs are not in English. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] if you want people helping you debug the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the XML that you are using looks as below

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

the XSLT to print the data into a table with all the values is as below. The `<xsl:for-each>` loop for the repeating `<cd>` elements will result in a tabular format for the data.

```
<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"> 
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                    <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right">Price</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right">Year</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="cd">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align:left"><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align:right"><xsl:value-of select="price" /></td>
                        <td style="text-align:right"><xsl:value-of select="year" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```